# Gson custom TypeAdapter implementation

Tags: android, gson

I am using **Retrofit** with **Gson** for deserialization.
I want Retrofit responses to be interfaces so I made **TypeAdapterFactory** that should be telling gson to deserialize **Interfaces to their class implementation.** In my case **FeedElement** is the interface, **FeedElementImp** is the class implementing it.

```
public class InterfaceAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
    if (FeedElement.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType())) {
        return (TypeAdapter<T>) new FeedElementAdapter(gson);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private class FeedElementAdapter extends TypeAdapter<FeedElement> {
    private Gson gson;

    public FeedElementAdapter(Gson gson) {
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, FeedElement value) throws IOException {
        out.jsonValue(gson.toJson(value));
    }

    @Override
    public FeedElement read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        return gson.fromJson(in, FeedElementImp.class);
    }
}
}
```

This, of course, is not working. I am registering this factory when creating the Gson with a builder. I guess the problem is in the FeedElementAdapter write/read methods.

```
private static ApiModule createApiModule(String baseURl, BoutAppPreferences prefs) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor(prefs))
            .build();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new InterfaceAdapterFactory())
            .serializeNulls()
            .create();

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURl)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));

    API api = builder.build().create(API.class);
    return new ApiModule(api);
}
```

Here is a sample API call.

```
@GET("api/feed")
Call<List<FeedElement>> getFeedItems();
```

As you can see Retrofit can't deserialize the FeedItem because it is an Interface. If I put Call> instead it will work fine.

Comment: What is the `deserialization");` part of the question doing?

Comment: @cricket_007 It was not fully erased irrelevant information.

Comment: How is it not working? What's the error?

Comment: @peitek The high-level error is Timing out

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of model objects, and you want to remove the use of reflection for (de)serialization of each one, suddenly you have to write many, many TypeAdapters.

You can use [Stag](https://github.com/vimeo/stag-java) library, Stag improves Gson performance by automatically generating reflection-less TypeAdapters for your model objects.

Comment: I don't really want to speed up Gson. It is fast enough right now. The problem is that Gson or Retrofit can't figure out that there is implementation of the Interface that I want them to return. So I have to implement adapter that tells Gson or Retrofit "InterfaceFoo de/serializes to ClassFoo".